# Scrolling UICollectionView uses lots of memory leading to crash

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I'm developing an Emoji keyboard. This is my approach:

- I decided to use UICollectionView. I do everything in code and don't intend to use Xib files.
- I create a subclass of UICollectionViewCell. This is going to contain a single label showing the Emoji. This is what I do inside its initWithFrame

  ```
  - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
          if (_label == nil) {
          _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

          _label.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

          _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
          [_label setNumberOfLines:1];
          self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;

          [self.contentView addSubview:_label];
          }
      }

      return self;
  }
  ```
- In UICollectionView dataSource object, I read a plist file containing an NSDictionary with NSString as keys and NSArrays as values. Inside each NSArray, one can find the emojis I'm going to show. I then store the dictionary in a property. Here is the code:

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *emojis;

  - (NSDictionary *)emojis {
       if (!_emojis) {
            NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EmojisList"
                                                        ofType:@"plist"];
           _emojis = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
      }
      return _emojis;
  }
  ```
- In the following method, I try to populate the cells:

  ```
  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

          NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

          EmojiCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
          cell.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.isiPad ? 47 : 33];

          NSArray *dataArray = [self.emojis objectForKey:self.categoryNames[indexPath.section]];
          cell.label.text = dataArray[indexPath.row];

          return cell;
  }
  ```

The problem I have, is that the memory usage increases when I scroll. This leads to crash on real device.

Please help me. I tested many different ways to solve this but I had no success.

This is a screenshot of instruments. I really don't know what those are about.

[image: Memory Usage increases when I scroll]

Comment: You need to run instruments to find out what part of your code is leaking memory. See: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: @rjstelling I've done that lots of times. It's none of my methods. Only some methods related to CFString or something. As I told in a comment below, I've found out that the memory usage is more when I set the font size to some higher value. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @mani Hi. I saw you helped someone with similar problem. Would you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Font size do the tricks.

"Apple Color Emoji" font replaces emoji characters to different size of PNG images based on font size. Bigger images soon use up 40MB memory limit.

In my case, I tried font size of 16 and use 1.5 scale transform to make it bigger enough. The result doesn't look good but at least it works...

Comment: Good explanation. Then how does Apple do it for its own keyboard? Especially on iPad. They are crisp clear. Keyboards like SwiftKey do it too and their keyboard doesn't crash.

Comment: @sdtaheri I don't think system keyboards have the same memory limit as low as third party keyboards. I think the better solution would be use own images instead of using emoji characters with special font. I will try this method later.

Comment: I'd be happy to know the result if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to offload the `UIViewCells` and contents out of the memory as you scroll and these cells are off the screen. `UICollectionView` should be doing that but I would double check.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be done automatically when it's dequeued? I've found out something rather odd. The bigger I make the font size, the more memory it uses!!

Comment: What part do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much memory is really allocated, but it really shouldn't crash because of the collection view. However, do realize that the keyboard, especially running on the iPhone 6+, is restricted to a rather small memory footprint. Having lots of cells shown with many subviews could therefore lead to memory issues like that.

However, I'm assuming that this is due to a retain cycle. Two classes are most likely capture each other strongly. This can happen in any kind of block or two strong properties referring to each other.

When you can't track down the point where this is happing it's probably the easiest way to just narrow down the code it can possibly be caused by.
Do so by for example not loading the emoji from the plist to check whether that code is affecting it.

I hope this helps, it's basically impossible to tell without looking through your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the plist from disk every time you load a cell? If so you are probably reading the plist into memory every time a cell is loaded and it isn't getting released again. Try disabling the code which reads the plist (put some test strings in the array for now) and see if that helps. If so, that's the problem.

Comment: Of course not! Look at the second code snippet. I only read from plist file when _emojis is nil. I also removed the plist file reading section and loaded the dictionary in code. It didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I have really same issue, 
Well, still issue is remaining but....

What I found is that when I use transform rather then UIFont.size, it reduces the memory usage quite a bit.

Comment: yep, i've tried it and my keyboard still use up to 30mb memory to carry 1200 emoji icns

Answer (score -1):

try set the label's opaque YES

Comment: checked snapchat UI with review tool , and it's label's opaque is set YES